# How to read two strings that contain spaces with scanf() in the same line, But separated by newLine ( \n )

Tags: c

I tried to write the following code:

```
int main(){
    1. char A[45];
    2. char B[45];
    3. scanf("%44[^\n]s%44[^\n]s",&A,&B);
    4. .....
```

But the problem is after I wrote the first string, and then press Enter (newLine) the program continues to the next command(line 4). And I can't insert data into array B.
The return value from scanf() is 1.
How can this be solved? it is very important that it be in the same command and not in two separate.

Comment: Remove the `s`, the `%[]` is a format on its own

Comment: Yes you are right, but it does not really matter - user3121023

Comment: Do the "strings" you want to read includes spaces? Can the string consist of of no characters like `"\nWorld"` --> `""` and `"World"`?

Comment: `scanf("%44[^\n]%*1[\n]%44[^\n]%*1[\n]", A, B)` is closer to what @avimenashe wants than `" %44[^\n] %44[^\n]"` which can read many line, not only 2.  avi,please provide more detail.

Comment: @avimenashe -- "Yes you are right, but it does not really matter": it does matter. `scanf()` is expecting a `char *` to receive the strings, but with `&A` and `&B` a `char (*)[45]`, i.e., a pointer to an array of 45 `char`s is provided. This is not the expected type, and `char *` and `char (*)[45]` aren't even compatible types. You have undefined behavior; this may _appear_ to work, but is not guaranteed to work, and may not work when other unrelated changes are made to the program, or for any other conceivable reason. You must provide correct arguments to functions.

Comment: @chux yeah just gave an example of two lines, the program I write includes a lot more, but I think the answer I got from -user3121023- was good enough for me. thx

Comment: @DavidBowling I do not really find the difference, after tracking the memory it seems that in both cases with or without ampersands the result is the same

Comment: @avimenashe -- As I said, it may _appear_ to work, but this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that anything at all can happen, including that the code seems to work in some circumstances. Enable compiler warnings to see a diagnostic for this; with gcc I suggest always using at least `gcc -Wall -Wextra`. C will allow you to do all kinds of things that you shouldn't; it is up to the programmer to know best. [The C Standard tells you what is UB.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)

Comment: Note also that compilers do not always provide diagnostics for code with UB. The programmer must know the language well enough to avoid it. C is not a good language to learn by trial and error or guesswork.

Comment: @DavidBowling thx for the explanation